# Two-Step Procedure to account for multicollinearity

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, two-step-estimation

Suppose the estimation equation is
$$
y=\beta _{0}+\beta _{1}x_{1}+\beta _{2}x_{2}+\varepsilon 
$$
where $\varepsilon $ is a disturbance and $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ are highly
correlated regressors. In a seminar, the presenter showed the results of the
following regression
$$
y=\gamma _{0}+\gamma _{1}x_{1}+\gamma _{2}\eta +\varepsilon 
$$
where $\eta $ is the residual of the regression of $x_{1}$ on $x_{2}$

$$
x_{2}=\alpha _{0}+\alpha _{1}x_{1}+\eta 
$$

**Question**: What would the advantage of this two-step approach?

Comment: It should give the same predictions, as $(x_1, x_2)$ have the same linear span as $(x_1, \eta)$. So this is just a change of basis.